# Find euclidean distance from a point to rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, euclidean-distance

i have a dataframe

```
id    lat      long
1     12.654   15.50
2     14.364   25.51
3     17.636   32.53
5     12.334   25.84
9     32.224   15.74
```

I want to find the euclidean distance of these coordinates from a particulat location saved in a list L1

```
L1 = [11.344,7.234]
```

i want to create a new column in df where i have the distances

```
id     lat     long    distance
1     12.654   15.50
2     14.364   25.51
3     17.636   32.53
5     12.334   25.84
9     32.224   15.74
```

i know to find euclidean distance between two points using math.hypot():

```
dist = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
```

How do i write a function using apply or iterate over rows to give me distances.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use vectorized approach

```
In [5463]: (df[['lat', 'long']] - np.array(L1)).pow(2).sum(1).pow(0.5)
Out[5463]:
0     8.369161
1    18.523838
2    26.066777
3    18.632320
4    22.546096
dtype: float64
```

Which  can also be

```
In [5468]: df['distance'] = df[['lat', 'long']].sub(np.array(L1)).pow(2).sum(1).pow(0.5)

In [5469]: df
Out[5469]:
   id     lat   long   distance
0   1  12.654  15.50   8.369161
1   2  14.364  25.51  18.523838
2   3  17.636  32.53  26.066777
3   5  12.334  25.84  18.632320
4   9  32.224  15.74  22.546096
```

---

**Option 2** Use Numpy's built-in `np.linalg.norm` vector norm.

```
In [5473]: np.linalg.norm(df[['lat', 'long']].sub(np.array(L1)), axis=1)
Out[5473]: array([  8.36916101,  18.52383805,  26.06677732,  18.63231966,   22.5460958 ])

In [5485]: df['distance'] = np.linalg.norm(df[['lat', 'long']].sub(np.array(L1)), axis=1)
```

Comment: Is one faster than the other?

Comment: Thanks so much for this, very useful.  A reminder for anybody that may come through in the future that latitude and longitude are not the same unit of distance and should be converted to a projection before calculating distance.

Answer (score 3):

Translating [(x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>]<sup>1/2</sup> into pandas vectorised operations, you have:

```
df['distance'] = (df.lat.sub(11.344).pow(2).add(df.long.sub(7.234).pow(2))).pow(.5)         
df

       lat   long   distance
id                          
1   12.654  15.50   8.369161
2   14.364  25.51  18.523838
3   17.636  32.53  26.066777
5   12.334  25.84  18.632320
9   32.224  15.74  22.546096
```

Alternatively, using arithmetic operators:

```
(((df.lat - 11.344) ** 2) + (df.long - 7.234) ** 2) ** .5
```